# How to embed YouTube live chat with super chat/stickers option enabled?

Tags: youtube, live-streaming, livechat

On YouTube, the live chat have options to super chat/stickers or to be a member.

[image]

Clicking on "$" opens the options to support the creator

[image]

Is it possible to get the same in the embedded YouTube live chat? Currently, if we embed using the following

```html
<iframe width="340" height="761.63" src="https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?v=jfKfPfyJRdk&dark_theme=1&amp;embed_domain=localhost" frameborder="0" title="YouTube live chat"></iframe>
```

It doesn't have option to support in the embeded chat.

[image]

Didn't find any significant information about embedding live chat and their options in the google developer docs.

- https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2524549?hl=en#zippy=%2Cembed-live-chat

Answer (score 1):

Interesting, you can even see when you [pop out](https://www.youtube.com/live_chat?is_popout=1&v=jfKfPfyJRdk) the chat, meaning that it should in theory be the exact same as the live chat, but doesn't have those stickers/channel subscription options.

My best guess is that this is no mistake by YouTube knowing their attention to detail, so perhaps it is to discourage streamers from hosting their streams on another platform, eg. their own site, by disabling this option on embeds.

There is also the possibility that because superchats/stickers etc involve **payment**, YouTube doesn't want to permit payment through embeds on another site, as this may lead to scam sites which pretend to use the 'official' superchat features, but in reality, just scam its users once they enter their payment information.